# Completely remove a subscription from Management Portal

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

In my Windows Azure Management Portal, I still see the "3-Month Free Trial" subscription although it has already expired and been canceled automatically. I've deleted both the hosted service in it and also the database, but it still doesn't disappear.

What can I do to completely remove a subscription?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visit the portal. In the upper-right corner, you should see a link for Billing.

[image: Billing link]

This will take you to a list of your subscriptions.

[image]
 Select your subscription. Then, on the right side, you'll see a few options, and one toward the bottom should be 'Cancel Subscription.'

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the subscription is already cancelled. As I wrote in my question, it is the 3-Month Free Trial that has been cancelled automatically after it has expired. Fyi: I have two other active subscriptions.

Comment: But does it still show up in the billing list? If it does, you should be able to contact Support and ask them to remove it.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks for your answer. I'll contact support then.

Comment: @xgqfrms - I'd suggest posting a new question if you have a specific issue - you're commenting on an answer I gave nearly 8 years ago, about a version of the portal that doesn't even exist anymnore. Also, remember that if it's not programming-related, it'll be considered off-topic (the guidelines of this site were different a long time ago). Microsoft Docs should have things covered in this area, or consider an Azure billing ticket.

Answer (score 42):

According to the Azure support it is (currently) not possible to delete canceled subscriptions.

> Greetings from Microsoft Azure.   I reviewed your request and would
>   like to mention that there is unfortunately no option to remove the
>   disabled subscription from the Azure portal. This is by design to
>   enable customer’s view the subscriptions purchased by them right from
>   the day the Azure account was created.

I consider this a bad design choice but that probably is just me.

Comment: I agree, I'd tend to favour the expected behaviour than the minority. A simple filter on the list to show expired/cancelled accounts would be a much better solution.

Comment: Okay the part that is *worst* is that it retains your payment information and there appears to be no valid way to remove one's payment information without replacing it with another valid card (!!). Is there anyway to strip this account down so I don't have a dormant account with my credit card attached to it? So insane.

Comment: Additionally, You cannot delete an Azure AD tenant until you remove all subscriptions.  A cancelled subscription cannot be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I cancelled a subscription a few months ago by calling support, and have had it sitting in the interface ever since.  Recently they notified me that they are going to delete it (and its associated storage) soon.  I expect it will disappear then.  Therefore I think they keep the subscription around for a while in case you ring them up and say "Heh, I didn't really want to cancel that!".

Comment: Same. I have disabled subscription that I cannot delete. I have been on almost a daily contact with tech support for over 2 weeks now, yesterday they emailed me that the subscription was deleted and asked me to check if it is gone in my Azure portal. It was gone. Yesterday. This morning it appeared again like nothing happened :) I contacted them again, waiting for response.........

Answer (score 2):

Additionally you also cannot get your account completely deleted either. You can request for subscriptions to be cancelled (as per original question) and Azure Support can action that but they can't/won't remove your actual account/login.

Comment: Yes it is, to some extent, but it seems that not deleting subscription means that it is internally still used even after nothing of your resources exists. I can imagine a couple of scenarios where deleting a subscription would require anonymization of some data as well on Azure side but that could go into the shade area of deleting data that are necessary to track at a later date. It seems to me that Microsoft is saying that all actions done in Azure are stored.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/cancel-azure-subscription#what-happens-after-i-cancel-my-subscription) it seems that subscriptions are permanently removed 30 to 90 days after cancellation.

Answer (score -4):

You can remove your subscription via Azure PowerShell.

How to install: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azureps-cmdlets-docs/

How to use: C:\PS> Remove-AzureSubscription "Test"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn495109.aspx

Comment: This doesn't remove your subscription from the portal. It just removes it from PowerShell's subscription file so that PowerShell won't find it.