# How can I cancel my Microsoft Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, subscription

I signed up for Azure Trial, but I don't use it anymore. However, they are still charging my credit card. I want to unsubscribe but couldn't find a way to do so. I tried to reach customer care also but there was no response.

How can I cancel / close my account?

Comment: Go through [**This Solution**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858470/completely-remove-a-subscription-from-management-portal)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming. See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) for details and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 13):

To cancel your account, login into Azure account portal @ https://account.windowsazure.com/Home/Index. Once you're in there, click on your subscription and you will see an option to cancel your subscription.

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone else who finds this: as of the posting of this comment, this only works in IE. In chrome, the submit button doesn't work.

Comment: As of this comment date, it does now work in Chrome.

Answer (score 10):

**There is no delete / close option in Azure. You have to cancel the subscription only.**

**For unsubscription**, you have to delete all resources individually within your account i.e. SQL server service, app services, Virtual machines, etc.

After that, you will be able to cancel the subscription as this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-how-to-cancel-azure-subscription) and below image

[image]