# Azure Account deleted automatically

Tags: azure, azure-policy

do you kown, when my azure account can be deleted automaticlly? Do I need to login from time to time on my accout to avoid losing my account? Does any policy exists for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I cancel my Microsoft Azure subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072168/how-can-i-cancel-my-microsoft-azure-subscription)

Comment: I personally dont know the answer to this one, hence I'm interested in knowing, but having said that - this question is probably not suitable for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

there is not a policy to control this. I would route your question to Azure Active Directory.