# Subscription I have been removed from, still showing in Azure Portal

Tags: azure

A couple of clients gave me access to their Azure subscriptions so that I could do work for them. The work has been completed and I asked them to remove my permission from their subscriptions.

They have done this but for some reason their subscriptions still show up in my list of available subscriptions when I click on my profile in the top right of the Azure Portal.

I can click on one of the subscriptions and switch to it, but I cannot see any of their resources, or create new ones. This confirms that I do not have permissions for that subscription anymore.

So if my access has been removed, which is it still showing up in the list of subscriptions which are available to me? Is there any way I can remove it from the list?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment.

The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561725/2959769) shows a reply from Azure customer care.

> Greetings from Microsoft Azure. I reviewed your request and would like
>   to mention that there is unfortunately no option to remove the
>   disabled subscription from the Azure portal. This is by design to
>   enable customer’s view the subscriptions purchased by them right from
>   the day the Azure account was created.

Comment: Aah, not quite the same situation, but it seems probable that the reason it still shows up for me is the same as for cancelled subscriptions. Thanks

Comment: Can you upvote this if not planning to accept as answer

Comment: Yeah sorry, was waiting to see if something more specific to my situation comes in with regards to an answer...

Answer (score 1):

This means you are still a **member** of the directory (even though you are no longer an admin of anything). You can ask the administrator of the directory to remove you.

You should also upvote this suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/13327620-remove-old-directories

Answer (score 0):

If you are a co-admin you can remove yourself by navigating to Settings->Administrators->Select->Remove from the classic portal (old)

Comment: I am removed from the subscription. The problem is that it still shows up in my list of available subscriptions though...

Comment: FYI, this removes you as an admin, but doesn't remove you as a member of the directory. I'm not aware of a process where a user can actually do this by themselves. This would have the effect of hiding the subscription from you in the old Azure portal, but it will still be listed in the new portal